# Expectation of functional of Brownian bridge

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

On Page 11 in [slides](https://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~bartlett/courses/2013spring-stat210b/notes/20notes.pdf), the process
$$
\sqrt{n}(\phi(F_n) - \phi(F)) = \phi_F'(\mathbb{G}_{n,F}) + o_P(1).
$$
We know that $\mathbb{G}_{n,F}$ converges weakly to is the F-Brownian bridge, defined as $\mathbb{G}_{F} = \mathbb{G}_{\lambda} \circ F $. We also have that $\phi(F) = F^{-1}(p)$ is the quantile function for $p\in[0,1]$.

I need to calculate the expectation of the above equation
$$
\sqrt{n} P (\phi(F_n) - \phi(F)) = \int \phi_F'(\mathbb{G}_{n,F}) {\rm d}F.
$$
I start by noting that by continuous mapping theorem 
$$
\int \phi_F'(\mathbb{G}_{n,F}) {\rm d}F \to \int \phi_F'(\mathbb{G}_{F}) {\rm d}F
$$
in probability. By definition of Brownian bridge I have that $\mathbb{G}_{F}$ is zero-mean Gaussian process with a finite variance. I also know that $\phi_F'$ is continuous on the domain. Can I then claim that
$$
\int \phi_F'(\mathbb{G}_{F}) {\rm d}F = \phi(\mathbb{G}_{F})
$$
? It seems easy but somehow I miss the interpretation of $\phi(\mathbb{G}_{F})$. What can I say about its distribution? Thanks for you help!